# Enable SSL for certain resource actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

I wish to enable SSL only for the create action for projects, how do I do that? Currently I have

```
  resources :projects, :constraints => { :protocol => 'https' }, :only => :create
  resources :projects, :except => :create
```

I don't think that's quite right though.

**UPDATED**

I have since changed it to

```
  match 'projects' => 'projects#create', :constraints => { :protocol => 'https' }, :via => :post
  resources :projects, :except => :create
```

I think this is better but is there yet a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Although you could create a [custom constraint class](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) to move the SSL logic out of the resource declarations, I recommend this [gem](https://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement). It will keep your routes file clean and force SSL only in production. (That logic could be baked into the custom constraint as well, but you would also have to manage the form links too.) You would do

```
class ProjectsController
  include ::SslRequirement
  ssl_required :create
end

<%= form_for(@project, projects_url(:secure => true)) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just tried this but it enforced https even in development env?

Comment: Wait, there are 2 versions https://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement and https://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement, what's the difference?