# How do I selectively enable SSL in Rails 4 for certain paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, https

How do I turn SSL HTTPS off for a given path? I saw [Enable SSL for certain resource actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796386/enable-ssl-for-certain-resource-actions) but that was to enable HTTPS for a single path. My config has

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

However when I show a page that has an iframe and embeds an external source

```
<iframe src='http://www.
```

Then it doesn't even appear (Chrome) because it is mixed content. So I want to disable SSL for that single route that has an iframe. (I really want to turn it on & off depending on the content.)

I tried adding this to my `routes.rb`

```
get 'frame', :constraints => { :protocol => 'http' }
```

but that gave an error `http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/136/frame`

```
No route matches [GET] "/posts/136/frame"
```

even though the route shows up

```
frame_post GET  /posts/:id/frame(.:format)  posts#frame {:protocol=>"http"}
```

I also saw [Force SSL for specific routes in Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605407/force-ssl-for-specific-routes-in-rails-3-1) and tried

```
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer' # Gemfile
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => [ /\/frame$/ ], :strict => true # application.rb
```

but it still always redirects to https. I also tried

```
force_ssl :except => :frame # posts_controller.rb
```

But that didn't work either.

I'm using Rails 4.1.

Answer (score 3):

Rack ssl enforcer is a great solution for this - your regular expression is wrong.  In your form, the regex would only exclude a path that is entirely '/frame', and would not exclude a path that had anything before /frame

If you want to exclude any path that **ends with** */frame*, The correct regular expression would be:

```
\.*\/frame$/
```

Resulting in a config:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => [ \.*\/frame$/ ], :strict => true
```